# Optimizing MySQL table indexes

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to reverse a date type index on a InnoDB database schema via. MySQL Workbench
But every time i try to apply the changes they are ignored?
Do i need to use the command line to configure the database?
According to http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/knowledge-zone/mysql-5-5-innodb-myisam-522945.pdf
Page 10. InnoDB supports BTREE indexes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reverse a date type index?"

Comment: The default order is ASCENDING
I would like to order some of the date columns in DESCENDING order.